# How to add host.docker.internal to Authorized redirect URIs for google OAuth Api

Tags: docker, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I have a microservice running in a docker container which connects to outside on

> host.docker.internal

these are /etc/hosts file in the container

> 192.168.65.2    host.docker.internal

How can I add `http://host.docker.internal:3006/callback` to Authorized redirect URIs in google OAuth API?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a public routable DNS entry, for Google OAuth to be able to redirect the user back to you after authentication. You can't use host.docker.internal.